# Is there a site users guide that describes the meaning of the various color schemes and other info encoding methods?

Tags: discussion, user-interface

I've noticed there are tons of brilliantly subtle ways the site encodes information. For example: if an answer's been accepted the number of answers on the main screen is colored green, or if <strike>you've voted up a question</strike> a question contains one of your interesting tags, the entire row goes blue.

Is there a description of all these little UI Easter Eggs, either on the main StackExchange site, in the FAQ or on the meta page? I've looked and cannot find anything, but this is also the only StackExchange site I use. If such a description existed, I think I'd be able to use the site more efficiently, as would others--especially newbies.

So I'm opening this question in case such a thing already exists. If it does I think we should link to it from the B&CG FAQ and if not we should add this info to the FAQ directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through the StackExchange FAQ link that Pat posted I found a question [specifically about the color scheme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22184/what-do-the-colors-on-stack-overflow-mean) for StackOverflow. It doesn't seem exhaustive and their scheme is a little different than here, but this is a more direct reference to the answer to my specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the site and I hope you find it useful.

While not a direct answer, I believe most of the answers you seek are contained within the [StackExchange FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites).

A lot of things are exposed as your reputation increases so you will see more and more as time goes on.

In general, questions about how a stackexchange site works (that aren't specific to us here at B&CG) are better directed at meta.stackexchange.com  There are also a **lot** of knowledgable people over there willing to answer questions about how things work.

Correction to your question - The row turns blue if it is tagged with one of your favorites.  There is no easy way to see which questions you have upvoted, which is the source of some [dissension](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64321/show-all-the-posts-i-voted-up-in-my-user-account-details).  :)